# Поиск минимального числа среди последних 4-х элементов на ассемблере

Tags: массивы, ассемблер

Есть код для поиска максимального числа среди всех элементов. Нужно переделать на поиск минимального числа среди последних 4-х элементов.

```
.model small  
.stack  
.data  
    message db "max = ", 30h,30h,"$"  
    string1 db 99,67,34,87,25,11,85,76,98  
    res db ?  
    strResult db 16 dup (0) ; string buffer to store result  
.code  
main proc  
    mov ax,seg message  
    mov ds,ax  
    mov cx,09h  
    mov bl,00h  
    lea si,string1  
up:  
    mov al,[si]  
    cmp al,bl  
    jl next  
    mov bl,al  
next:  
    inc si  
    dec cx  
    jnz up  
    mov res,bl  
    xor ax,ax  
    mov ax,bx  
    mov cx,10  
    xor bx,bx  
divide:  
    xor dx,dx  
    div cx  
    push dx  
    inc bx  
    test ax,ax  
    jnz divide  
    mov cx,bx  
    lea si,strResult  
next_digit:  
    pop ax  
    add al,'0'  
    mov [si],al  
    inc si  
    loop next_digit  
    lea di,message  
    lea si,strResult  
    mov bx,[si]  
    mov [di+6],bx  
    mov ah,09  
    lea dx,message  
    int 21h  
main endp  
end main
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Нужно начать с 4 с конца элемента, поэтому

   ```
   lea si,string1
   ```

   нужно поменять на

   ```
   ; к адресу начала прибавляем длину массива и вычитаем 4 - получаем адрес 4 с конца элемента
   lea si, string1 + 9 - 4
   ```
2. Нужно пройти только по 4 элементам вместо 9, поэтому количество итераций, заданное через регистр `cx` меняем с 9 на 4:

   ```
   mov cx, 4
   ```
3. Нужно найти минимум вместо максимума. В примере программы начальное значение максимума (0) записывается в регистр `bl`. В данном случае проще всего за начальный минимум принять первый из 4 элементов:

   ```
   ; к адресу начала прибавляем длину массива и вычитаем 4 - получаем адрес 4 с конца элемента
   lea si, string1 + 9 - 4  
   mov bl, [si]
   ```

   И еще нужно поменять условие в цикле на противоположное: `jl next` заменить на `jg next`

Итого получается примерно такой фрагмент кода:

```
    mov cx, 4 ; Пройти по 4 элементам
    lea si, string1 + 9 - 4 ; Начиная с 4 элемента с конца
    mov bl, [si] ; минимумом изначально считать первый из этих 4 элементов
up:  
    mov al, [si]  
    cmp al, bl  
    jg next ; если текущий элемент больше значения в bl - перепрыгиваем
    mov bl, al ; если не больше, считаем его новым минимумом
next:  
    inc si  
    dec cx  
    jnz up
```

---

Еще один вариант - начинать с конца и двигаться в сторону начала списка:

```
    mov cx, 4 ; Пройти по 4 элементам
    lea si, string1 + 9 - 1 ; Начиная с последнего элемента
    mov bl, [si] ; минимумом изначально считать первый встреченный из этих 4 элементов
up:  
    mov al, [si]  
    cmp al, bl  
    jg next ; если текущий элемент больше значения в bl - перепрыгиваем
    mov bl, al ; если не больше, считаем его новым минимумом
next:  
    dec si ; двигаемся в сторону начала массива, поэтому вместо inc нужно делать dec
    dec cx  
    jnz up
```

Comment: СПАСИБО ОГРОМНОЕ ТЕБЕ, ПРОСТО ЛУЧШИЙ